# How to install a bundle that doesn't belong to any feature?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

There is a bundle in the `p2` repository(e.g. https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-06 ) that doesn't belong to any feature, how do I install it ?

As far as I can tell, I can't install it through `p2` because the things `p2` manages directly are `features`. In other words, I can't install it through the following interface:
[image]

All I can do is download this bundle separately and put it in the `dropnins` directory to use it.

Is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to mention which bundle it is? You can use the P2 Director to install it from the CLI: http://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

Comment: @nitind Thanks. I've found the feature to which the bundle I wanted to install belongs, and I've been able to use the bundle by installing the feature.
But I still have two questions: 1. You mentioned the CLI approach, but it can only install features, not bundles, right? 2. Does a bundle under the p2 repository necessarily belong to a certain feature?

Comment: 1. No, the Installable Unit is the bundle's name 2. I'm not sure, but it wouldn't matter.